Enabling K2 in Android Studio stops gradle build kts files being "recognised"
I have migrated to kotlin 2.0.10 and enabled the K2 compiler in Android Studio
now i see this message in all my gradle build kts files

this is the version of Android Studio i am using
Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1
Build #AI-241.15989.150.2411.11948838, built on June 10, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11609105 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.5
Kotlin Plugin: K2 Kotlin Mode (Alpha)
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 8192M
Cores: 16
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
  ide.instant.shutdown=false
  ide.experimental.ui=true

in addition theres no code highlighting or code completion in my kts build files.
is there anyway i can resolve this? other than disabling K2?

Open the Settings on the projects screen:

Change the VM Options with K2=false:

